# Set global settings for Latex Printing in sympy

Tags: python, latex, settings, sympy

I want to use the latex() command from sympy a lot in my code.
However I want every multiplication to be printed with a dot, and I do this by adding mul_symbol= "dot" after the variable I want the latex form of.

Can I make these setting global, so I don't have to add it every time?
This is the documentation: http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/printing.html#sympy.printing.latex.latex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default settings are in the internal variable `_default_settings` of class [LatexPrinter](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/68e4e7bbae6e30c94ec98831aeb0e013707f3ddf/sympy/printing/latex.py#L123). You *could* create a new instance of LatexPrinter with your own settings:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.printing.latex import LatexPrinter
my_printer = LatexPrinter(settings={"mul_symbol": "dot"})
var('x y z')
print(my_printer.doprint(x*y+y*z))
```

but it's much easier to write a one-line function instead:

```
def my_latex(expr):
    return latex(expr, mul_symbol="dot")

print(my_latex(x*y+y*z))
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the answer from user6655984 and the autocomplete from vscode I could find the that adding the following worked.

```
from sympy.printing.latex import LatexPrinter
LatexPrinter.set_global_settings(ln_notation=True,mul_symbol="dot")
```